# VBA: Activate method not found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some VBA code that was working perfectly a few weeks ago, but now is crashing with an error. The code, which is triggered from Word, is meant to open an Excel file. The specific error I'm getting is related to the Activate method.

```
Sub Populate()

Dim eApp As Excel.Application
Dim eWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim eSheet As Excel.Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set eApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
   ExcelWasNotRunning = True
   Set eApp = New Excel.Application
End If

'Open Workbook
WorkbookName = "(Excel file location)"
eApp.Visible = True
eApp.Activate
Set eWB = eApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName)
eWB.Activate

(etc.)
```

I'm a VBA novice so I'm sure there's a better way to write the above. It's the final line - eWB.Activate - that creates a compile error, "Method or data member not found." Again, this was working last month and isn't working now. Has something changed in Office 2016 that makes this code illegal?

I played around and think I have a workaround, but I'd still like to know why this is crashing, for future reference. Thanks.

EDIT: [Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5PF3.png)

Comment: Is the [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/777/getting-started-with-excel-vba/6489/adding-a-new-object-library-reference) to Excel 16.0 ? I can't see any issues with the code, but there is no need for `.Activate` because `.Open` activates it.

Comment: @AndrewKilmer activation of an excel instance is controlled by the operating system and not VBA/Excel, however the easy way to do it is to activate a workbook that is open in that instance and the that Excel application instance will be activated automatically.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, when you open a workbook, it is the ActiveWorkbook so you don't need to Activate it. Also put `On Error GoTo 0` before open the WorkbookName, so you can see proper error.

Comment: @PatricK Can you elaborate on what `On Error GoTo 0` should be doing? I tried that and got the same result.

Comment: @Slai I'm definitely getting the error on eWB.Activate. The code runs if I comment that out (well, for a while - it errors out the next time I try to do something with eWB).

Comment: @Ibo That is the line that is generating the error, though. `eWB.Activate` is meant to activate the open workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know why you have that Error when you have `On Error Resume Next` from there on. Are there codes missing from what you have posted? Also is the Excel workbook macro enabled that may interfere the codes in Word?

You may also try Late Binding for those Excel Objects once you are done coding with IntelliSense. Just to demonstrate how I would code this Excel file open part (Excel 2010):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Populate()

    Dim eApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim eWB As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim eSheet As Object ' Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
    Dim WorkbookName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set eApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If eApp Is Nothing Then Set eApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelWasNotRunning = eApp Is Nothing

    If ExcelWasNotRunning Then Exit Sub
    'Open Workbook
    WorkbookName = "C:\Test\Tables.xlsx"
    eApp.Visible = True
    'eApp.Activate
    Set eWB = eApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turns on Debug prompt on Error
    If Not eWB Is Nothing Then
        With eWB
            .Activate
            ' process stuff
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
        Set eWB = Nothing
    End If
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I added `Dim WorkbookName As String` to my original code (and nothing else) and it worked. I don't know why this one change makes it run, or why it worked before, but nonetheless this is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: When you do not define variables with `As xxx`, it is of type `Variant`, which causes `eApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName)` to fail as it's expecting a String. So the *eWB* is Nothing and hence **Nothing.Activate** is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this from word and it worked, I think somehow you have an early binding problem, which is most likely is due to installing a new version of word on your machine. You can google it and clean your registry to get rid of it.

```
Sub Populate()

    Dim eApp As Object
    Dim eWB As Object
    Dim eSheet As Object

    On Error Resume Next

    Set eApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err Then
       ExcelWasNotRunning = True
       Set eApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    'Open Workbook
    WorkbookName = "\\grid\sasprod\ci\reports\Quickmarks\Quickmarks Tables A.xlsx"
    eApp.Visible = True
    eApp.Activate
    Set eWB = eApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName)
    eWB.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I actually did not use parentheses in the actual code. I only inserted them in the sample code above to indicate where I put the location and filename. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Andrew Kilmer can you just post the excel file location string then? I ran the same code with the string that was a path to a file on my computer and the code did not throw an error

Comment: @AndrewKilmer Do you run this code from Excel or Word? Also take a picture of the error message and post it to help more

Comment: The Excel file location is `"\\grid\sasprod\ci\reports\Quickmarks\Quickmarks Tables A.xlsx"` - we use a SAS Grid file system here. I ran the code from Word. Is it possible to paste an image into a comment? I tried CTRL-I per the Markdown instructions and nothing happened.

Comment: @AndrewKilmer edited my answer just now, it should work

Comment: Yes, this code is working. It seems like changing the 'Dim' lines to reference 'Object' instead of specific Excel objects is doing the trick.

Comment: @AndrewKilmer then please hit the check mark next to the answer